# $e^x = \cos(x) + 1$ with elementary functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, roots

This question just got asked by a user and then closed, even though unanswered. I have doubts that it is even possible to express the root in terms of elementary functions.

> By attempting to solve
> $$
> e^x = \cos(x) + 1
> $$
> I quickly recognised that this probably has no simple solutions. Now I'm asking myself the question whether there is some sequence that converges to the root of
> $$
> e^x-\cos(x) -1 .
> $$
> So far I couldn't find one. Does somebody have any ideas? (I should find the solution in terms of elementary functions / constants, the latter consisting of $e$ and $\pi$, i.e. in particular no numerical solution but an "exact" in this sense)

Comment: Please do not repost deleted questions.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I don't understand? If I find this question interesting, why am I not allowed to repost an unanswered (and closed) question?

Comment: There is a reason why the question has been closed. You can see the closed question to see the reason. Obviously your question will also be closed with the same reason.

Comment: Because you must draw the interest of the community. Showing the work/ideas you contribute is one good way to do so. So is a reason we, not just you, might be interested in the problem.

Comment: The problem with this sort of question(s) is that it appears random. Why $e^x$? Why $\cos x$? Why not $3e^2x=2\sin x+3\cos 4x+\pi$? A random question of that type almost certainly has *no* solutions expressed via elementary functions. In other words, either there is something special about *this particular question* (in which case this needs to be spelled out as a "context") - or there is nothing special and thus drilling deep into it is an exercise that few will want to embark on, as it is most likely going to be fruitless.

Answer (score 3):

Consider that we look for the negative zero's of function
$$f(x)=e^x-\cos(x)-1$$ they are located close to $a=-(2n+1)\pi$.

Using a series expansion around $x=a$, we have as an *approximation*
$$f(x)=e^{a}+e^{a}(x-a)+\frac 12(e^{a}-1)(x-a)^2+O\left((x-a)^3\right)$$ and then the roots
$$x_\pm=a+\frac{e^a \pm\sqrt{e^a \left(2-e^a\right)}}{1-e^a}\quad \text{with}\qquad a=-(2n+1)\pi$$
Some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
n & \text{estimate} & \text{exact} & \text{estimate} & \text{exact} \\
 0 & -3.400353505 &  -3.400592904 & -2.792500392 &  -2.789129646 \\
 1 & -9.437402316 &  -9.437402397 & -9.411992194 &  -9.411992104 \\
 2 & -15.70851212 &  -15.70851212 & -15.70741411 &  -15.70741411 \\
 3 & -21.99117230 &  -21.99117230 & -21.99112485 &  -21.99112485 \\
 4 & -28.27433491 &  -28.27433491 & -28.27433286 &  -28.27433286 \\
 5 & -34.55751923 &  -34.55751923 & -34.55751915 &  -34.55751915
\end{array}
\right)$$

This is the **simplest** approximation.

It can be improved using the $[2,m]$ Padé approximant of $f(x)$ and the solutions are still obtained at the price of a quadratic equation in $(x-a)$. The formulae will not be given here but the results for the first negative root are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 m & x_- & x_+ \\
 0 &  -3.40035350459848 & -2.79250039185374 \\
 1 &  -3.39992453955299 & -2.79144452980351 \\
 2 &  -3.40059832774563 & -2.78918524129760 \\
 3 &  -3.40059015587550 & -2.78914785893247 \\
 4 &  -3.40059296364765 & -2.78913037876924 \\
 5 &  -3.40059289328230 & -2.78912978260528 \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
\infty & -3.40059290398227 & -2.78912964643395 
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

This could be improved using a better choice of $a$. Expanding the first derivative as a series around $x=-(2n+1)\pi$ and then series reversion, we have the maximum value at
$$a'=a+\frac{e^a}{1-e^a}+\frac{e^{3 a}}{2 \left(1-e^a\right)^3}+\frac{e^{3 a} \left(1+2 e^{2 a}\right)}{6 \left(1-e^a\right)^5}+\cdots$$ Using this truncated series, for $n=0$,
$a'=\color{red}{-3.09636}404$ while the "exact" value is
$   \color{red}{-3.09636393}$

The process used in the first part of this answer is now repeatable with $a'$ instead of $a$.

Comment: What is $x_0$? ${}$

Comment: @Gary. Just a typo ! Thanks for pointing it.